# Visible not working asp element (literal, image, label)

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Wasting my time on the following issue:

```
 <asp:Literal ID="myId" runat="server" Text='<%# User == null ? "Yes" : "Nope, failwhale" %>' />
```

However, this is not displaying anything at all.

```
<asp:Literal ID="myId" runat="server" Text="This works." />
```

What am I missing here? I've tried hiding an ImageButton by setting:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibCreateCredit" src="../../images/factuur.gif" alt="create" runat="server" Visible='<%# User.IsInRole("IsAFish") %>'  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Eval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe(v=vs.110).aspx) function:-

```
 <asp:Literal ID="myId" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# (Eval("User") == null ? "Yes" : "Nope, failwhale") %>' />
```